# Detect url of window that opened my angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a way in angular to know from where is my application been opened? I mean if my application is opened from another tab or window, how can I get the URL of window from where is doing the call? thanks

Comment: How do you "call" an application?

Comment: Hi @kvetis I have another app with a button to open my app in a new tab, and I need to check from where is called my application because need to do a filter based on the url who open the new tab, do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

When a window/tab is opened from a different window/tab, you can access the address of opener using following js:

```
window.opener.location
```

The prerequisite to use that is that the link that opened the window has `rel="opener"` attribute, since modern browsers don't allow access to opener by default.

Comment: Thank you. I was finding lots of articles about reverse tabnabbing as a problem but nothing that explained why I couldn't seem to replicate it in the browsers on my machine anymore. Sure enough, if I add `rel="opener"` via the inspector and then click the links I can tabnab the opener.

Edited to include the [Chrome](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6140064063029248), [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1522083), and [Safari](https://webkit.org/blog/8475/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-68/) documetation on when this was done.

Answer (score 0):

If the other app is also yours, add some "place_id" to the URL to open your app. Different "place_id" from different places. And analyze it in the app via "window.location" or via router parameters.